# How I can integrate new relic with my API

Tags: go, newrelic

I want to set up new relic in my go existing ap step by step.

I am unable to monitor with my Go API.

I have followed [the documentation steps](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/go-agent/installation/install-new-relic-go/).

From github.com/newrelic/go-agent, use your preferred process; for example: bash command `go get github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic`

Import the github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic package in your application.   `import github.com/newrelic/go-agent/v3/newrelic`

Initialize the Go agent by adding the following in the main function or in an init block:

```
app, err := newrelic.NewApplication(
    newrelic.ConfigAppName("Your Application Name"),
    newrelic.ConfigLicense("YOUR_NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY")
)
```

NOTE: I have followed all the trouble shooting as well.

Any help would be appreciated and maybe this isn't the best way to accomplish this, open to suggestions.

Comment: This might help you - https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/go-agent/get-started/introduction-new-relic-go/

Comment: Using the same doc but I am unable to monitor my go project with new relic

Comment: It is better to ask for help when you are stuck at specific steps instead asking for a step by step solution. You question clearly shows no research and effort.

Comment: sorry, I have updated my question